# "... need XXX-ing" vs. "... need to be XXX-ed"

Tags: meaning, differences, infinitives, gerunds

What is the difference between these two expressions?

> 1. Your hair needs brushing.
> 2. Your hair needs to be brushed.

Comment: Hugely related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24163/using-ed-vs-ing-in-the-needs-washed-construction

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes. This question is answered there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.  Just two different ways to say the same thing.

- Your hair needs to have a brush applied to it. -
- Your hair needs to be brushed.
- Your hair needs a brushing.
- Your hair is very ugly and should be cut off completely.  Forget the brush.

Sorry about that last one. I am just joking.  Your hair is fine. :-)

Answer (score -1):

No difference, it is purely stylistic.

A very small hint that in 1. you have to do it yourself, and in 2. you will have it done

Comment: I beg to differ.  Either one could be done by yourself or another.

Comment: I am British, and I just mentioned the possibility of a very tiny difference, as the common use in our tiny and remote islands.

Comment: Not so tiny, and not so remote!  I lived there for a few years, once upon a time, and I found I could not see the sea from Cheltenham!  Even from Cleeve Hill!  BTW, I did not downvote you.

Comment: Being British does not make one make that distinction.