# "Needs repairing" vs. "needs to be repaired"

Tags: meaning, differences, infinitives, gerunds

Do the following two sentences mean the same thing? If so, which is more commonly used?

> 1. My car needs repairing.
> 2. My car needs to be repaired.

Comment: You can say: "I need **to repair** my car" but not, "I need repairing my car"

Comment: I disagree this is a duplicate of the question suggested by @EdwinAshworth The OP is not asking when or if a gerund should be used. It's a question about *meaning*.

Comment: I agree Edwin's suggestion is not the best fit, and yet this question has been addressed on this site several times before, see e.g. the second paragraph in [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/24165/300).

Answer (score 0):

No difference in meaning as far as I am concerned. No idea which is used more. Both part of everyday speech.

Comment: I disagree with this and agree with Martha on the other question. "Needs to be repaired" means it needs to be fixed completely, while "Needs repairing" suggests any amount of tinkering will do, the result not necessarily being a car that runs at all.

Comment: @RegDwigнt It is not a distinction I recognise.