# Usage of a verb " to need" with to-infinitive or -ing form: change in meanings

Tags: meaning, gerund-vs-infinitive

The [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing) says that **the meaning of a verb "to need" can change depending on what you have used after it: to-infinitive or -ing form.**

I haven't comprehended it completely. Could someone, please, give me any examples of this change in meanings.

**P.S.**: is this related to a fact that need can be sometimes in a role of a semi-modal verb?

Comment: Related to [this recent question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/360061/15299); check out the discussion there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You need to correct your ways." means that the speaker thinks that you need to change something in yourself.  "You need correcting." means that the speaker wants to change you himself.