# Help diagramming a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, diagramming

Can someone diagram this sentence:

> I thought it was best to let you decide to whom this needs forwarded.

In addition, is the sentence grammatically correct?  If not, why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Central Pennsylvanian English speakers: what are the limitations on the "needs washed" construction?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/central-pennsylvanian-english-speakers-what-are-the-limitations-on-the-needs-wa)

Comment: Note to British readers: it appears that "sentence diagramming" means something specific to many Americans: the application of a particular method, which I presume is the Reed-Kellogg system mentioned in [sentence diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_diagram).

Comment: @Peter Shor: Although *needs washed*, etc., seem awful to me, I do appreciate that it's normal in some US dialects. But surely users of this form are normally perfectly well aware that it's non-standard for the rest of us. Doesn't this imply that such speakers probably *wouldn't* use it in the same sentence as the much more formal **to whom**?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: No, judging from [the questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9331/should-i-say-needs-cleaned-or-needs-to-be-cleaned) we've had on this site, some of these speakers are unaware that it's not normal English.

Comment: @Colin: "sentence diagramming" is something that used to be taught in elementary schools in the U.S. -- I certainly had to do it in the 1960s. I don't know whether it is pedagogically useful; I found it extremely tedious. My impression is that it is no longer in the curriculum where I live, but it may still be taught in some areas of the U.S.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure diagramming is possible on Stack Exchange, even if anyone wanted to do it. The sentence is grammatical, except for the last word. British English, at least, would require *to be forwarded*.

Comment: Except in Yorkshire.

Comment: @ColinFine Or Scotland

Comment: In British Standard English,then.

Answer (score 2):

For the grammaticality of this statement, it uses the "needs washed" construction, regional in the U.S. to central Pennsylvania and environs, and which has been discussed here in [these](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24163/using-ed-vs-ing-in-the-needs-washed-construction) [three](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9331/) [questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/central-pennsylvanian-english-speakers-what-are-the-limitations-on-the-needs-wa). If you're not in a region where this construction is used, you should say "needs to be forwarded". As for how to diagram "needs forwarded", since it's not a standard construct, I don't know whether there's a standard way of doing it.