# Omitting "to be" after linking verbs

Tags: linking-verbs

According to a grammar book called Grammar in Use

> Before a noun we include to be when the nouns tells us what the
>   subject is, but often leave it out when we give our opinion...We leave
>   out to be in formal English.

For example :

> He walked into what seemed to be cave. ( not ... what seemed a cave.)
>
> She seems (to be) a very efficient salesperson.
>
> The job turned out (to be) far easier.

And apparently we cannot omit **to be**  if linking verb is followed by a verb as follows :

> The television seems to be working okay now.

I couldn't find many references regarding this question on the internet so I'd like to ask  that do we have to omit **to be** especially in formal writing even if it is followed by a noun phrase? or is it a strict rule always true?

And can we omit to be before a verb or noun phrase in casual writing as follows ? How do they sound?

The television seems working okay now.

He walked into what seemed cave.

Comment: See a lot of other threads on things like "needs cleaned".  For example http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9331/needs-cleaned-or-needs-to-be-cleaned?s=1|3.076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a strict rule.  I generally use 'to be' in both formal and informal contexts.

In your second example, you can't omit the verb in the first case, it needs to say

> The television seems to be working okay now

For the second I think you could say either

> He walked into what seemed a cave

or

> He walked into what seemed to be a cave

Comment: I see. I assume  you agree that  "He walked into what seemed a cave" sounds more formal than "He walked into what seemed to be a cave"  ?

Comment: Yes, more formal or maybe more literary.  I would still be inclined to use 'to be' though.