# Is it okay to omit "to be" when using adverbs and infinitives?

Tags: adverbs, infinitives

Which of the following is correct?

> 1. The room needs cleaned.
> 2. The room needs cleaning.
> 3. The room needs to be cleaned.

Comment: #2 and #3 are correct

Comment: Not okay to omit.  Omit, so-spelled. What are infitivies?  Anything like skivvies?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24163/how-are-needs-to-be-washed-needs-washing-and-the-regional-variant-needs-w, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/central-pennsylvanian-english-speakers-what-are-the-limitations-on-the-needs-w, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9331/needs-cleaned-or-needs-to-be-cleaned

Comment: @vpn Wouldn't this be a duplicate if the title were corrected? Isn't a close-vote appropriate?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, I don't know how to mark a question a duplicate of multiple questions. And since none of those was marked a duplicates of  another, I wasn't sure how to flag it.

Comment: @vpn Hit 'close' and choose one duplicate. Your other comment will still be seen. Earlier duplicates should have been closed before, but the site isn't perfect.