# Not sure if this is grammatically correct

Tags: verbs, word-usage

This floor needs mopped. Please find the janitor.

Comment: It's grammatical in Pittsburgh. It's ungrammatical in London. [See this blog post](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/needs-washed).

Comment: As a native Brit, I think it's OK, myself.

Comment: It's a widely-used construction in the United States. Elsewhere, find a sociolinguist to tell you.

Comment: @JohnLawler -- It's never been widely-used in any part of the US I'm familiar with, and it makes English teachers wince all over the world.  It should be either "This floor needs mopping" or "This floor needs to be mopped".

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9331/needs-cleaned-or-needs-to-be-cleaned

Comment: Well, then English teachers all over the globe will just have to wince, I'm afraid. Serves them right for believing in zombie grammar. If they want to find out the actual facts, instead of another ignorant opinion, they can check the link @PeterShor obligingly provided, which I repeat here: https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/needs-washed.

Answer (score 2):

It is grammatically correct, consisting of elision/omission of "to be" (this floor needs to be mopped). Having said that, you would be more likely to hear "this floor needs mopping" in UK English.