# Can "to be" be ommitted if it's implied? e.g. "These items need completed by Friday"

Tags: grammar, phrases, american-english, pennsylvanian-english, needs-pp

Can "to be" be ommitted if it's implied?

i.e. Are the following sentences acceptable grammar?

> "These items need done by Friday"
> "These items need completed by Friday"

Obviously this is a more-clear way to word it:

> "These items need ***to be*** done by Friday"
> "These items need ***to be*** completed by Friday"

But all my life I have thought the first method was also grammatically correct. Today that was questioned by a coworker.

Is this a regional thing?

Edit: Appears similar to ["Needs cleaned" or "needs to be cleaned"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9331/needs-cleaned-or-needs-to-be-cleaned), which has an answer.

Comment: I would prefer to omit _need_ and keep the _to be_, as in _These items to be completed by Friday_, if omitting was at all necessary.

Comment: In western PA and nearby places, yes. It works with *need, want*, and sometimes *like.* It apparently drives others bonkers. The dog needs emptied, the car wants gassed.

Comment: Standard English does not allow "these items need done".  But some dialects may allow this.  (For example Pennsylvania Dutch.  See http://padutch.net/what-is-pd/ )

Comment: In most US dialects that sort of wording suggests that the speaker is poorly educated.

Comment: "These items need completion by Friday" would work, in most contexts.

Comment: What can be said in informal British English is that something "needs doing" by a certain date.  But the 'doing' would probably be interpreted as a verbal noun.  The word 'done' cannot be interpreted as a verbal noun, even, as far as I know, in US dialect.

Comment: Ah, yes!!  "To be" or not "to be".  That is the question!!

Comment: *need verbing* is fine according to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/need) e.g. "this shirt needs washing", "East Yorkshire pig farmers don't need reminding of that." No indication that it's informal or non-standard.

Comment: This is governed by the verb _need_; the usual name for the phenomena is ["Needs Washed"](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/needs-washed).

Comment: @HotLicks What fates impose, that men must needs abide.