# "Done soon" vs. "soon done"

Tags: grammar, adverbs, word-order, colloquialisms

There are a number of colloquial expressions common to my area ([see here, for example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/central-pennsylvanian-english-speakers-what-are-the-limitations-on-the-needs-wa)).  I'm relatively recent to the area, so there are a number of expressions that just sound unnatural to me.  However, I'm not certain of this one.

I'm used to saying "I'll be done soon," or "will you be done soon?"  Yet the phrasing I hear most often around here is "will you be soon done?" or "I'll be soon done."  Which is grammatically correct?  Is one a colloquialism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My logic says that it's a syntactical borrowing from Pennsylvania Dutch.  In German the phrase would be "Ich bin bald fertig. (literally: I am soon done.)"

Comment: That would certainly fit with the culture.