# "Needs to be X" vs "Needs X"

Tags: colloquialisms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using -ed vs. -ing in the “needs washed” construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24163/using-ed-vs-ing-in-the-needs-washed-construction)

I've always used the following construct:

> The book **needs to be read** before Thursday.

But I've heard some people say:

> The book **needs read** before Thursday.

Which is correct? Or perhaps both?

Answer (score 3):

People around Pittsburg usually say *needs read* but most of the rest of the US would say *needs to be read*.

I believe *needs to be* is the grammatically correct version, but have a personal liking of the first (shorter) version.

Comment: I suspect it's very much a spoken dialectal usage, but I'd always thought it was only used in contexts where the rest of us would use the present continuous (as in *"This car needs washing/needs wash"*). Personally I'm not keen on *"This book needs reading before Thursday"*. Does that affect whether it can *"need read"*?

Answer (score 2):

"Needs" is a transitive verb, so it needs some kind of noun as its direct object.

> The book needs to be read before Thursday.

is one candidate; "to be" is an infinitive functioning as a noun, and since it needs to be *something*, we use the past participle of the verb.

Or you might skip all that and just take the gerund form of the verb by appending the *-ing* suffix to it, which turns it into a noun:

> The book needs reading before Thursday.

This is perhaps a more informal construction, and it might sound slightly awkward to some people, especially because of the "before Thursday" at the end.

> The book needs read.

is unacceptable to many educated speakers, because the past tense "read" doesn't function as a noun in any normal situation. I live in Arkansas, so I hear people use this construction occasionally, but very rarely from careful speakers.

Answer (score 0):

The first option is more common/standard, however the second is common in certain dialects. See [Central Pennsylvanian English speakers: what are the limitations on the "needs washed" construction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5407/2007)