# Is there difference between "go with" and "come with"?

Tags: word-choice

There is no social shaming that comes with knowing nothing about our local politicals. (Joe Clein Column, Time Magazine, August26)

Can I change "come with" into "go with" here? It seems to me that "go with" is too much used as an idiom to mean something  essentially or normally goes together with something else. But here the author is just to negate any necessary relation between the two things.

Is the difference between "come with" and "go with" based on, or related to, the difference between "come" and "go"? Maybe the difference between them is just a product of habit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using "with" without an object pronoun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118852/using-with-without-an-object-pronoun)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think [Using “with” without an object pronoun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/118852) is more about using “with” **without an object pronoun**, as in (eg)   “Are you going with?” and  “Do you want to come with?”, while this question is more about the **difference between** “go with” and “come with”.  Different questions, different answers.

Comment: Yes, it is based on the [difference between _come_ and _go_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/5-ComingAndGoing.pdf). Yes, you may use either one here. And absolutely **everything** in language is "just a product of habit".

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion*, the two are interchangeable in this situation as expressions of concomitance, although this is not always the case. You couldn't apply this to phrases like "wine goes well with steak," for example. Additionally, it makes more sense to say "wisdom comes with age" than "wisdom goes with age." In fact, those sound like completely opposite statements!

I don't know if there is a hard-and-fast rule here, so I would suggest sound judgement on a case-by-case basis. Sorry if this wasn't the answer you were looking for.

*Obviously, this is not a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can associate 'come' as a reaction to follow another to a position already held and places the object as a subject to the one giving the command. While 'go' is proactive and allows the object to take on the lead ahead of the current position, or places the object on an equal term as the one giving the command toward a destination.

I guess it can be viewed upon the perspective of the position one wants to place on an object relative to the one giving the command and the desired direction to move.

Answer (score -1):

"Come with" is not generally used without an expressed direction: come *up* with; come *down* with; come *out* with; come *across* with; although informally come with means: To accompany someone. There is a sense of movement and travel (physical or mentally) and implies a bringing about of the situation.

Whereas, "go with" is used in the sense to "give one's consent or agreement to (a person or proposal)" and in the above quote the "social shaming" is an accompaniment to the ignorance of "local politicals" [sic].