# Declining use of such phrases as to be

Tags: grammar

2-Part Question:

1) What is the grammatical term for "to be" in the following statement? "This needs to be repaired."

2) Is it slang or an accepted trend that more and more the "to be" portion is dropped? Statement phrased as "This needs repaired."

Comment: Part 2 is pretty much answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5407/191178).

Answer (score -2):

1) The verb be/am/is/etc. is referred to as a "copula". "be" is the infinitive form of the copula, and "to" is generally analyzed as being a particle that's part of the full infinitive (that is, "be" is the bare infinitive, while "to be" is the full infinitive).

2) "Standard" English require the copula. Forms without the copula can be considered "slang", "nonstandard dialect", "regionalism", etc., depending on one's preferred nomenclature.

Se for example https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/needs-washed

Comment: This corresponds to a German idiom: _Dein Auto gehört gewaschen_, lit. "Your car belongs washed," but I'd expect "needs washed" to be much further east of Pittsburgh if the German had been any influence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Be" is a copula that can be used in an auxiliary role. Those are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Huddleston et al may agree, but Quirk et al don't.  It's misleading to trot out one analysis as if it's the only one that linguists subscribe to. I've adjusted my comment.

Comment: [Comment 2 in sequence, emended] This is 'be' in an auxiliary, not a copular, role, according to Quirk, Greenbaum et al.